# Increment var each time an event is triggered and display value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to increment a variable each time I write 'yes' in the input field, but the `n` value always stays at '1' in the console.

```
$('#txt').on('keyup', function() {
    let n = 0;
    if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
        n++;
        console.log("You wrote 'yes' " + n + " times");
    }
});
```

I'm missing something here but I don't know what. How do I keep incrementing `n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reset the `n` variable every time you click because it's *inside the handler*. So every time that handler is run, a new variable is created with the initial value. Declare and initialize it outside the event handler:

```
let n = 0;
$('#txt').on('keyup', function() {
  if($(this).val() == 'yes') {
    n++;
    console.log("You wrote 'yes' " + n + " times");
  }
});
```

This way, the variable *is not redeclared and initialized to 0 every time you click*, it exists outside the handler.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're declaring the variable inside of your listener. Put it outside of your listener.

Answer (score 1):

declare `n` outside event handler, like this:

```
let n =0;
$('#txt').on('keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='yes'){
        n++;
        console.log("You wrote 'yes' " +n+ " times");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope? just put the variable n outside the event callback ;)